# IWebElement doesn't have properties when initialized using PageFactory

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

When I declare my IWebElement like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input#raffle_submit")]
private IWebElement _buyNowButton;
```

And initialize it in the class constructor using PageFactory:

```
PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
```

Then when I make a break point in any method in order to look at the element's properties I see no properties in this element:

```
public CartObj ClickBuyNowButton()
{
     _buyNowButton.Click(); //here is my break point
}
```

Only property I see is: - `Non-Public members` : http://prntscr.com/8k90r4

**So where are all properties that must be in IWebElement like "Enabled", "Displayed" and so forth?**

**More to say:** I don't have any problems with using this element, I can click on it, I can send keys to it but when I use the next JavaScript code it tells me that argument is wrong (but it worked well before):

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement);
```

**Error that I appears after executing JS code above:**

```
 Additional information: Argument is of an illegal 
    typeOpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver+EventFiringWebElement
```

I'm sure it's connected with version of WebDriver.

**So my current WebDriver version** is 2.47.0

**ChromDriver version** is 2.19

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: What you see in the debugger is actually just a *proxy object*. The `PageFactory` initializes your `_buyNowButton` with a proxy which will only be resolved once you use it somewhere in your script. So unless you actually use it, you won't see any properties like `Displayed` or `Enabled` in the debugger.

As to your second question: I can't recreate that now with Selenium 3 and the latest ChromeDriver, but it may have been a bug back in the day.